# How to get value from router request?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have created an angular app. In this app, I want to add a search. for this, I have a textbox and a button. Textbox name is name="search"

I have a get method in API.

```
router.get('/allActivities',  (req, res) => {

    Activity.find({ name: req.body.search }, (err, activities) => {

        if(err) {
            res.json({success: false, message: err});
        } else {
            if(!activities) {
                res.json({success: false, message: 'No recent activities found'});
            } else {
                res.json({success: true, activities: activities});
            }
        }
    })

});
```

This is the get request. In this, I'm trying to get the text box value from angular front end

```
Activity.find({ name: req.body.search }, (err, activities) =>
```

This is MongoDB

But I'm not getting any output. The matter here is I'm not getting a value for this "req.body.search" which I used to get text box value. can anybody tell me how to do this?

if I put

```
Activity.find({ name: 'Roshini' }, (err, activities) =>
```

like this, I'm getting the output. So pretty sure that I'm not getting  textbox value to this get method correctly, :/

Comment: why you didn't use ngModel for that textbox and get the value by using ngmodel?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? Because i dont understand how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Html side**

```
<input ng-model="search">
```

**Angular Controller**

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/allActivities?search='+$scope.search
}).then(function (response) {
        $scope.activities = response.data || response
    }, function (response) {
        alert(response)
    }
);
```

and on backend access it by **req.query.search** or **req.params.search** rather than **req.body.search**

Comment: It's query not params

Comment: How do i send the request? can you explain me a little bit

Comment: You can use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) on angular side...

Comment: Im sorry, im using angular 2. Can you show me how to this in angulr 2?